# Install a phone app made with Visual Studio (c#) in a non Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, mobile, windows-phone, maemo

Is it possible to accomplish that?

How should I do that?

The phone specs:

- Nokia N900.
- OS: Maemo 5 (Linux based).

My PC OS: Win7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look, you Phone OS is Maemo, your app is for Windows.

You forgot the Windows Phone version but never mind, it's not going to work.

The closest thing would be a Mono implementation, but there isn't one compatible with WinCE (or WP7).

Answer (score 2):

No, it has the wrong operating system.

Answer (score 1):

[You can use Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Maemo).

You will need to write the application specifically for Maemo; it cannot run WP7 applications.

Comment: Good luck with using any Phone feature (dialing, ...) in a VS project. You'd have to start with Mocking an entire phone first.